# Why NAT type detected by `stun` command depends on used STUN server?

Tags: nat

```
# stun -v stun.counterpath.net |&  grep '^MappedAddress\|Primary'
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:20458
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:20458
Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin 

# stun -v stun.wtfismyip.com:3478 |& grep '^MappedAddress\|Primary'
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:27763
Primary: Independent Mapping, Independent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin    

# stun -v stun.l.google.com:19302 |&  grep '^MappedAddress\|Primary'
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:30710
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:30711
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:30711
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:30711
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:30711
Primary: Independent Mapping, Independent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin

# stun -v stun.1und1.de:3478 |&  grep '^MappedAddress\|Primary'
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:29003
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:29003
Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin

# stun -v stun.xtratelecom.es:3478 |&  grep '^MappedAddress\|Primary'
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:28160
MappedAddress = 93.84.76.218:28160
Primary: Independent Mapping, Port Dependent Filter, preserves ports, no hairpin
```

Why it is sometimes "Port Dependent Filter" (i.e. evil, P2P-unfriendly NAT) and sometimes "Independent Filter" (a "good" NAT)? What is the actual NAT status in this case?

The detected type is consistent if the same STUN server is used.

## NAT type

Tested with three carrier-grade NATs (home, work, mobile) - they seem to be port-restricted according to `stun` tool when used at appropriate servers, but some servers just always give "Independent".

Comment: It would greatly help if you detail what the network looks like, the network device models (especially the NAT router) and the network device configurations. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question to provide the necessary information.

Comment: I suspect that some STUN servers only have one address available and proper `stun` test requires two IPs. Insufficiency is misreported as wrong NAT type. But that's just hypothesis, not confirmed.

Comment: Unfortunately, host/server configurations are off-topic here. You can ask about that on [sf] for a business network. We can help with NAT configurations for on-topic network devices, e.g. enterprise-grade routers.

Comment: I installed coturn Debian package and the `stun` command says `Independent Filter`. On CentOS, it says the same with stuntman server but with coturn it says `Port Dependent Filter`. All installations were done on a VPS using 1 IP address only so I guess that is not the problem and a second IP address is not necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594390/why-a-stun-server-needs-two-different-public-ip-addresses/8373718#8373718 Can we change a STUN server to `Independent Filter`? By the way, why do you say `Port Dependent Filter` is not P2P-friendly? It worked with WebRTC on a WAN.